# Address Bar for Google Map API, which element to use

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I would like to follow the same UI in Google map in its address bar, where one can enter an address.

I am creating a web Polymer app which uses the map. 
Question is which element should I use for the address bar? Is it considered **floating**? Samples are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the browser address bar.  If so `<iron-location>` and perhaps `<app-location>` and `<app-route>` are what you use.  If you just want in input in the screen, perhaps `<paper-input>`.  Need more info

Comment: @akc42, I don't mean the address bar on the browser, more like input for an address like in Google map. From your idea, paper-input-container may be better/versatile since it offers different elements, again like in the Map.

Comment: @akc42, If you provide working code samples below, I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

This example is not complete as it needs some behaviours that are elsewhere and pikaday imported which I have modified.  But it should give a good idea as how to use a paper-input to do other stuff

```
<!--
`<pas-date-input>` us an element to collect dates from users.  It is designed to provide
as comprehensive approach to entering dates into an input field as possible.

As soon as the user focuses the input a date picker dialog is displayed, although focus remains
with the user in the input field.  The user can type parts of dates into the input field, and the
date picker dialog adjusts itself its interpretation of that date - jumping to todays date when
date is invalid.

The date is ultimately expected to be in the format dd/mm/yyyy, but it is only set that way if
the user clicks on the date picker dialog, otherwise it is left in the imperfect form in the input field.  So if the user enters some digits without any "/" characters this is assumed to be just a year (valid in the range 1901 to 2049 inclusive) before 4 full characters are typed, the year is estimated by what is being input with 3 digit years having a final 0 automatically appended.

As single "/" characted may mean dd/mm or mm/yy.  If a valid dd/mm can be interpreted from this then that is preferred, with the current year being assumed.  If the number after the slash is too large to be a month then mm/yy is assumed.

@param vague is defined then loss of focus will leave the text in the input field as it was.  If not the final worked out date will replace it
-->

<dom-module id="pas-date-input">
  <template>
     <style include="pikaday-style">
     :host {
        display: block;
      }
      :host {
        @apply(--pas-date-input)
      };
       #anchor {
        position: relative;
       }
       #container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: -20px;
        z-index: 9998;
        background-color: #fff;
       }
       #field {
        width: var(--pas-date-field-length);
       }
    </style>
    <pas-date-validator id=validator></pas-date-validator>
    <paper-input
      id="field"
      label="[[label]]"
      auto-validate
      prevent-invalid-input
      allowed-pattern="[0-9/]"
      validator="pas-date-validator"
      error-message="dd/mm/yyyy"
      value="{{value}}"
      disabled="{{disabled}}"></paper-input>
    <div id="anchor">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script src="/scripts/pikaday.js"></script>

  <script>
  /* global Pikaday */
  Polymer({
    is: 'pas-date-input',
    properties: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        value: '',
        notify: true,
        observer: '_valueChanged'
      },
      vague: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      },
      disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
    },
    behaviors: [
      PAS.DateUtils,
      Polymer.IronValidatableBehavior,
      Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior
    ],
    listeners: {
      'field.focus': '_gotFocus',
      'field.blur': '_lostFocus'
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.scopeSubtree(this.$.container, true);
    },
    attached: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.pikaday = new Pikaday({
        container: this.$.container,
        minDate: new Date(1901,0,1),
        maxDate: new Date(2049,11,31),
        onSelect: function(date) {
          self.value = [
            ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
            ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            ('000' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-4)].join('/');
        }
      });
      this.pikaday.hide(); //ensure it starts hidden
    },
    detatched: function() {
      this.pikaday.destroy();
    },
    _valueChanged: function(value) {
      /* jshint boss: true */
      var d;
      if (this.pikaday && this.pikaday.isVisible()) {
        if ((d = this.strToDate(value)) && d !== true) {
          this.pikaday.setDate(d,true);
        } else {
          this.pikaday.setDate(new Date(),true);
        }
      }
    },
    _gotFocus: function() {
      this.pikaday.show();
      this._valueChanged(this.value);
    },
    _lostFocus: function() {
      var date = this.pikaday.getDate();
      this.pikaday.hide();
      if ((!this.vague && this.value.length > 0) ||
        (this.value.indexOf('/') < 0 && this.value.length > 4) ||
        (this.value.indexOf('/') > 1 && this.value.length > 6) ||
        (this.value.indexOf('/') > 0 && this.value.length > 7)) {
        this.value = [
            ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
            ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            ('000' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-4)].join('/');

      }
    },
    _getValidity: function() {
      return !!this.strToDate(this.value);
    }
  });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to use paper-input. Your example is too hard for me to follow though. However I still have the problem on making it "float" on the map. When a user scrolls down to the bottom, the input element disappears. I need to show the input "always".

Comment: Use a relative div (or possibly the body tag) and a container div for the input which is absolute. I bit like the anchor and container in my example above.  This should then float above everything else

Comment: I am now using a similar idea as in your anchor with "position: relative". However my issue may be unique since I have been using "<paper-scroll-header-panel  fixed main>". Hence there is a header part, <div class="paper-header">, and the content, <div class="content">. My paper-input is contained in the header. The main issue with that is the margin/padding on the left/right is a white space instead of the Map, like in Google map.